# Cannot import Keras on Pycharm

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, keras

I tried to code on Pycharm, but when I use `from keras import backend as K` it throws an import error like "cannot import name backend". But I can do it on terminal.

How can I fix this?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUO8M.png)

[on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc7Sv.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm cannot find installed packages: keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620014/pycharm-cannot-find-installed-packages-keras)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your PyCharm sees the same Python environment as what you are using in Terminal?

See if this possibly works for you:
[use tensorflow on pyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712237/use-tensorflow-on-pycharm/42718495#42718495)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem:
Check here:[Pycharm cannot find installed packages: keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620014/pycharm-cannot-find-installed-packages-keras)

After adding new package to project interpreter, you need to quit Pycharm and restart it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```python
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

instead.